# Looking for WSO2 JMS parameters for monitoriong the traffic manager queue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm looking for JMS beans for monitoring the queues status of the WSO2 traffic manager in cluster environment that has traffic manager VS multiple gateways.

Our understanding is that the gateways send API requests counts to the traffic manager as binary/thrift messages, and at the same time they are subscribed to traffic manager decisions, sent as JMS topics.

Our assumption is that there are multiple queues used for this bidirectional communication, and we want to measure the state of those queues, if they are getting full, etc.

Looking at the WSO2 list of beans (curl http://localhost:9404/metrics) I saw many AMQP and MB related parameters, but playing with them I did not find any meaningful parameters.

If anyone is aware of any relevant parameters I'll be happy to give it a try and share the findings.

Answer (score 2):

There is a DB called WSO2MB_DB.mv.db and its stored the JMS topic related data in traffic manager. its located in <APIM_HOME>/repository/database folder. It will help you to find some details about creted queues and topics.